# Custom Wordpress REST API Endpoint (Users and their latest posts)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

For a "instagram story"-like feature, I need to query all users that posted in the last 24 Hour and their latest post that are not older than 24 Hours via the REST Api.

Is this possible? Do I have to create a custom endpoint or something?

Comment: Wordpress REST API doesn't have this kind of filter out of the box. You'll have to add a new endpoint. Please refer to http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

Comment: any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read the docs I added to my previous comment? Actually, here is a more up-to-date page: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/